# Hypersonic dynamic shift in large vs. small lifting bodies

Tags: reentry, aerodynamics, mass

Background:
*Lifting bodies have been tested at small scales, though not during re-entry. For instance: the NASA HL10

Such Lifting-Body designs are seemingly here to stay with craft such as Dreamchaser or the ESA IXV.*

My question does not specifically relate to the above examples, but is dependant on them.

**HOW does the size of a lifting body (or really any re-entry vehicle) affect it's flight dynamics, etc.**

Examples of larger planned LB's for reference:
BAC MUSTARD: http://www.astronautix.com/m/mustard.html
Douglas Astro: http://www.astronautix.com/d/douglasastro.html

Comment: Are you familiar with aerodynamic scaling parameters, .e.g. Reynolds number?